# Random app crashes while starting application in android

Tags: android, forceclose

Sometimes my application crashes while trying to open it. As the app hasn't completely started I don't get an error report. I also can't connect my application to the emulator because this behaviour is not reproducable. Sometimes it just crashes once. In other times I can try to open/reopen it as often as I want and it works perfect.

I only use the network-connection (no camera and other stuff). I don't have any services which could crash the application and I tried to reproduce my error by trying to stop the application while it loads something in the background - no success at all.

What do you think could be the reason for crashing? How can I get a log-file, stacktrace something useful for fixing this problem? I simply can't reproduce it so I never see a Logcat-Output when it occurs.

It might be a Fragment-Initializing-Problem but I can't see my mistake. This never occured before and it's just not a common mistake. It might crash only once/twice a week - but it crashes in some point in time...

I've uploaded my project on [github](https://github.com/Dalanie/SimpleNews) but I don't think this is helping somehow.

My main question is: What for opportunities do I have to see what might be the reason behind these random crashes?

Comment: i guess the problem is your network connection.

Comment: need to post the logcat for the "sometimes"

Comment: do use asyntask when you are making http request and handle it.also check before making request whether internet is available or not

Comment: like I said, my phone is never connected when this error occurs. I tried for hours to reproduce it - but this is just never happening... sometimes the app doesn't crash for days

Comment: @wqrahd I'm using Volley for the whole NetworkConnection. I don't use AsyncTask at all - I use Handlers - Do you think that this might be a problem in case I close the application and a handler is receiving a message?

Comment: yes..thats also an issue.

Comment: whats your log cat says..?

Comment: I never have my phone connected to the computer when the error occurs - so I don't have any logcat output. It's just not reproducable

Comment: try to connect your phone to computer then test it several times and see if you get logcat

Comment: To get the crash report use `Crashlytics` or `BugSense` ... Google it !! easy to use :)

Comment: you don't have to be connected, you just need to connect to a computer soon enough after the crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Root your phone and install CatLog. When it crashes, open CatLog and save the log so you can view it later.

**Or try this if you want to automate it:**

Create an exception handler that saves a stack trace to a file.

```
public class UncaughtExceptionSaver implements UncaughtExceptionHandler{

    UncaughtExceptionHandler previousHandler;
    Context context;

    public UncaughtExceptionSaver (Context context){
        this.context = context;
        previousHandler= Thread.getUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    }

    @Override
    void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e){

        /*Save the stacktrace from the throwable to a 
          file in your external directory, using context. */

        previousHandler.uncaughtException(t,e);
    }
}
```

Then in an Application subclass, call this in the `onCreate` method:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionSaver(this));
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't. Sometimes the app just crashes before it gets to caught these exceptions... and I can't figure out why this is happening

Comment: Did you try CatLog? There must be something in the log (I think).

Comment: Found the error. Unfortunately one of my Fragments didn't have an empty constructor. Still don't get why this is not tracked by UncaughtExceptionHandler...

Comment: Weird. So I'm guessing if your Fragment doesn't have an empty constructor, there are cases where Android tries to instantiate it through reflection and fails?

Comment: Might be..., I would expect a stacktrace anyway.. because it enters the onCreate-Method of my Activity and crashes as soon as it tries to instantiate the Fragment. However my problem is solved and your answer is the most helpful ;) thanks again